# BulkCopy or other method; appending Access 07 table into Sql Server 2005

Tags: ms-access-2007

So I am working in access as i have no other programs on my work computer. I have a linked table "dbo.returns" and i can easily copy that into access and use an update query. what I'm trying to do is take those updates and append them back into the SQL database. I was able to use a pass-through query to delete the table records in a few seconds. all i had to write was:

DELETE dbo.returns

and it cleared out all the records. however i cannot find anyway to quickly append records. using a standard access query to append will append 700 records in 10seconds or 50,000 records in 20-30minutes. I'd like to cut down on this as the total amount of records for this table is 300,000 and i have 2 other tables i need to update with 3-4 times as many records.

is there any way i can write a simple Pass-through query like i did with the delete? i have been trying to use BulkCopy or BulkInsert but I am very unexperienced with writing modules and have been unable to find any guides that i can figure out. i can't figure out what goes into a module and what goes into a query. any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

If you have your data in an access table, you can use the Import wizard of the SQL Server to load the data, much faster. Always faster to get the Server to do the work.

Comment: thanks i saw that i can export from access and want to try that from either side. but need 'create table' permission. can i import that data into a current table without making a new one if i import from SQL? i have no familiarity with SQL server